# Why DCFL is not closed under kleene star?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties, pushdown-automata

I have read somewhere that DCFL is not closed under kleene star. but I haven't found any example

Comment: Where did you read this? Have you tried expressing any not-deterministic CFL you know in terms of a starred DCFL?

Comment: @Raphael One example is Problem 2.23 in Sipser 3rd ed.: "Show that the class of DCFLs is not closed under the following operations: a) union, b) intersection, c) concatenation, d) star, e) reversal."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The language $\{a^nb^nc^k \mid n,k \ge 1\} \cup \{a^nb^kc^n \mid n,k \ge 1\}$ I believe is a standard example of a non-deterministic context-free language. At least intuitively it is clear that we can push the $a$'s, but we do not know when to pop (compare with $b$'s or with $c$'s?)

The language $L = \{ a^nb^nc^k \mid n,k \ge 1\} \cup \{d\;a^nb^kc^n \mid n,k \ge 1\}$ however, *is* deterministic. The $d$ prefix gives away which part we are in.

Now consider $(\{d\} \cup L)^*$.

Comment: And even $\{d\}^* \cdot L$!

Comment: @Raphael True, but that does not help to answer the question, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Nope, but it helped me believe that $(\{d\} \cup L)^*$ is not in DCFL.

Comment: @HendrikJan What does that $d$ prefix do exactly? You say it gives away which part we are in. What do you mean by that?

Comment: @tenepolis One half of the language starts with letter $a$, the other half with letter $d$, so the automaton can *deterministically* decide how it will use its stack to accept the string it reads. Without the $d$ this is no longer possible, the machine has to guess what to store, hence it no longer is deterministic.

Answer (score 3):

#### Disclaimer

This is a hopefully improved version of the answer of @RAGHAVAMAJJARI. I wrote it to understand what is going on in the proof.

#### Claim

The Kleene closure of a deterministic context free language DCFL is not a DCFL.

#### Proof

Let $\newcommand{\lang}{\mathcal L}\lang = \lang_1 \cup \lang_2 =  \newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}\newcommand{\Nset}{\mathbb N}\set{c a^n b^n \mid n \in \Nset\cup\set 0} \cup \set{ a^mb^{2m} \mid m\in\Nset}$, which is a deterministic context free language thanks to the letter $c$ in front of every word in $\lang_1$. If $\lang^\ast$ is the Kleene closure of $\lang$, any string $x\in\lang^\ast$ should be a concatenated permutation of words $y_i \in \lang$, with the concatenation repeated numerably many times, zero included.

Now let $y_1 = c$ and $y_2 = ab^2$, which are both clearly in $\lang$. This can be seen by letting $n = 0$ and $m = 1$ in the sets $\lang_1$ and $\lang_2$. Because of this, the word $cab^2$ is in $\lang^\ast$, which can again be seen by in the first iteration taking $c$ and on the second iteration taking $ab^2$ from the set and forming a concatenation of these two words.

As both parts of the union that form $\lang$ are DCFLs, they are both recognized by the deterministic pushdown automata (DPA) $A_1$ and $A_2$,
which are shown in the two below images respectively.
In order to recognize the word $y_1y_2 = cab^2$, you would have to form a new automaton $A = A_1A_2$, by connecting the individual automata appropriately. However, this connection cannot be made deterministically.

[image]
[image]

Suppose it could. But as demonstrated in the below picture, the only way to recognize the word by combining the two automata $A_1$ and $A_2$ would be to either have a spontaneous transition $\newcommand{\trans}[1]{\overset{#1}{\longrightarrow}} s_1\trans{\epsilon, \sqcup/ \epsilon}t_0$ (where $\sqcup$ is the base symbol used to initialize the stack), or $s_1 \trans{\epsilon, \epsilon / \epsilon} t_1$. This is not deterministic behaviour, as now there is an empty transition out of a state that already has a non-empty transition out of it. This is a contradiction.

[image]

Therefore the set of DCFLs is not closed under the Kleene closure. We are therefore done with the proof.

Answer (score -2):

[image]
 proving kleene closure of DCFL is not DCFL

Comment: Could you please transcribe your image into text? You can use LaTeX here.