# What are the closure properties of LL(k) languages?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, formal-grammars

Suppose I have two LL languages $L_1, L_2$, both describable by LL($k$) grammars for the same $k$, and regular language $R$. Which of the following are also LL languages, and can they be described by LL($k$) grammars?

- $L_1 \cup L_2$ (union)
- $L_1 \circ L_2$ (concatenation)
- $L_1^*$ (Kleene star)
- $L_1 \cap R$ (intersection with a regular language)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All of these (except possibly Kleene closure) are answered (in the negative) in [Rosenkrantz & Stearns, Properties of Deterministic Top-Down Grammars, 1970](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0019995870904468).

For an example of a language whose Kleene closure is non-deterministic, see [this answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/58271/4416) by Hendrik Jan.

Comment: Ouch... I'll definitely read that for the proofs.

Comment: Actually, I might have misremembered the Kleene star closure. Rechecking.

Comment: Just in case, added another reference for Kleene star.