# Is LR(1) closed under concatenation?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties, lr-k

Suppose I have two LR(1) languages $L_1$, $L_2$. Is
$L_1 L_2$ (their concatenation) guaranteed to also be LR(1)?

References to proofs would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a special case of [What are the closure properties of LL(k) languages?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130682/what-are-the-closure-properties-of-llk-languages), where the answer is provided: no.

Comment: @reinierpost this question is about LR languages, not LL languages

Comment: Oops, thanks ... and I cannot find a statement for LR(1) languages either way. Deterministic context-free languages as a whole are not closed under concatenation; proving this is an exercise in: https://archive.org/stream/HopcroftUllman_cinderellabook/Intro+to+Automata+Theory%2C+Languages+and+Computation+_+John+E+Hopcroft%2C+Jeffrey+D+Ullman_djvu.txt