# Is LR(1) closed under union?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties, lr-k

Suppose I have two LR(1) languages $L_1$, $L_2$. Is $L_1 \cup L_2$ also LR(1)?
References to proofs would be very helpful.

Comment: This is a special case of [What are the closure properties of LL(k) languages?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/130682/what-are-the-closure-properties-of-llk-languages), where the answer is provided: no.

Answer (score 4):

A simple example is
$$L_1 = \{a^i b^i c^j \mid i,j\ge 0\}$$
$$L_2 = \{a^i b^j c^j \mid i,j\ge 0\}$$

Clearly, both languages are $LR(1)$. (Indeed, they are $LL(1)$.) But their union is inherently ambiguous, so not $LR(k)$ for any $k$.

This is also the usual example for non-closure of context-free languages over intersection. $L_1 \cap L_2$ is $\{a^i b^i c^i \mid i\ge 0\}$, the classic non-context-free language.