# Shuffle of a DCFL and a regular language

Tags: regular-languages, automata, context-free, pushdown-automata

This is problem 88 from Miscellaneous exercises of Kozen's "Automata and Computability".

> The shuffle $A||B$ of two languages $A$ and $B$ is defined as $\{w \mid w = a_1b_1\ldots a_kb_k,$ where $a_1\ldots a_k ∈ A$ and $b_1\ldots b_k ∈ B,$ each $a_i,b_i ∈ Σ^∗\}$.
>
> 1. Show that if $L$ is context-free and $R$ is regular, then $L||R$ is context-free.
> 2. If $L$ is a DCFL, is $L||R$ necessarily a DCFL? Give proof.

The first part is easy by the product construction. I believe that the shuffle of a DCFL and a regular language is not necessarily a DCFL but I am unable to come up with a proof. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $L$ is a DCFL and $d$ a symbol, then $\{d\}^*{\cdot} L$ is not necessarily a DCFL. Thus DCFL is not closed under pre-concatenation with regular languages.

An example of that is given in a related answer [Why DCFL is not closed under kleene star?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/58271/4287) (see the comment by Raphael below that answer!)

> The language $L = \{ a^nb^nc^k \mid n,k \ge 1\} \cup \{d\;a^nb^kc^n
> > \mid n,k \ge 1\}$ however, *is* deterministic. The $d$ prefix gives
> away which part we are in.

It now follows that DCFL are not closed under shuffle with regular $\{d\}^*$, as we can intersect that shuffle with regular $\{d\}^*\{a,b,c\}^*$ without losing determinism.